# timeout when starting_server_in_the_background in calabash android using calabash console

Tags: cucumber, calabash, calabash-android

I have updated my gemfile -

```
frozen_string_literal: true

source "https://rubygems.org"

git_source(:github) {|repo_name| "https://github.com/#{repo_name}" }
gem 'calabash-android', '0.9.5'
gem 'rubyzip', '1.2.1'

gem "rails"
```

and also added this in gemfile as well
source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
gem 'calabash-android', '0.9.5'
gem 'cucumber'
gem 'mongo'
gem 'json'
gem 'rubyzip', '1.2.1'
```

but still having issues - RuntimeError: Failed to start application. Starting took more than 60 seconds: HTTPClient::ReceiveTimeoutError - execution expired. Can anyone help to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in `calabash-android 0.9.6`. the workaround is working if you use the `calabash-android 0.9.5` and `rubyzip 1.2.1`.

Your configuration is ok but you need to delete the `instrument_backend` app in the application list on the devices too. Check [this thread](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/issues/893#issuecomment-422410250).